# Lists<> in loop

Tags: c#, list, loops

I have a problem in using list in the loops and I appreciate if any of you guys can help me.
I want to create a list and populating it from  array (named in my code: sarray) with the values bigger than -999. But the problem is when the values are less than -999, the code dumps the previous items of the list and  the size instead of being 40, is 27 (as if new list list is created)!

```
  List<double> nums = new List<double>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            if (sarray[i] > -999)
            {
                nums.Add(sarray[i]);

            }
        }
```

these are the values:

> [31411.0857 31411.0902 31411.0847 31411.0858 31411.0859 31411.0479 31411.0649 31411.0895 31411.0944 31411.0207 31411.0683 31411.0717 31411.075 31411.0825 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 31411.0156 31411.0718 31411.0719 31411.0884 31411.0885 31411.0936 31411.0896 31411.0897 31411.0537 31411.066 31411.0661 31411.0556 31411.0701 31411.0731 31411.0952 31411.0716 31411.0776 31411.0803 31411.091 31411.0911 31411.0919 31411.0919 31411.0919 31411.0919 31411.0919 31411.0919 ]

Comment: Please show a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Don't quite understand the problem you face, it would seem that `27` numbers from `sarray` are `> -999`. Remember **-998 is greater than -999**

Comment: what are the values in sarray?

Comment: ok now what about the rest of them? Can you post the values please? Remember you can edit your question.

Comment: these are the values: [31411.0857
31411.0902
31411.0847
31411.0858
31411.0859
31411.0479
31411.0649
31411.0895
31411.0944
31411.0207
31411.0683
31411.0717
31411.075
31411.0825
-999
-999
-999
-999
-999
-999
-999
-999
-999
-999
31411.0156
31411.0718
31411.0719
31411.0884
31411.0885
31411.0936
31411.0896
31411.0897
31411.0537
31411.066
31411.0661
31411.0556
31411.0701
31411.0731
31411.0952
31411.0716
31411.0776
31411.0803
31411.091
31411.0911
31411.0919
31411.0919
31411.0919
31411.0919
31411.0919
31411.0919
]

Comment: @Amir, I moved that into your question, please kindly delete your last comment.

Comment: If the list was cleared when the code encountered the group of -999 values, you would end up with 26 items, not 27.

Comment: @Guffa If the list was __cleared__ and there are in fact items that are < -999, then this question is missing some important pieces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The generic list takes an enumerable in one of its [overloaded constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0), and you can use the Linq `Where` extension method to constrain the items to add:

```
var nums = new List<double>(sarray.Where(d => d > -999));
```

You state that `-999` represents a "null" value for you, in that case you could change the `Where` to not assume the valid values are greater than -999:

```
var nums = new List<double>(sarray.Where(d => d != -999));
```

I believe this style expresses the intent more clearly than crafting your own loops.

As an aside, `double.NaN` might be a more obvious representation of an invalid value.

---

> But the problem is when the values are less than -999

This is because you are only checking where values are greater than -999: `if (sarray[i] > -999)`

However, the value dump you provided doesn't have any items that are less than -999 so this check will suffice - so long as the data set remains the same.

Comment: I believe he wants to only add certain items to the list (though not my downvote)

Comment: @EricJ. Amended, went straight to the code and skimmed the blurb too quickly lol

Comment: @EricJ. In that case the downvoters should swing by again and be as constructive as you are - now my perfectly valid answer is incorrectly downvoted. Wish we had the ability to @ downvoters lol

Comment: @KirkWoll I fixed it quite quickly, you can still remove your downvote. And yes I know it is broken, that's why I put the comment down - hopefully passers-by will read the content before assuming a downvoted item needs more downvotes.

Comment: Guys Thank you for the help. I really appreciate all of your kindness :)

Comment: The values doesn't have any values less than -999, but it has values *equal* to -999, which doesn't return true for `sarray[i] > -999`. As I showed, the posted code with the posted data *does work*.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: That's to you. In your answer you are pointing to a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Guffa Does not exist in the confines of the stated question, which has been cut down to what the OP thinks is relevant, even though the question itself states about values less than -999. Neither of us knows whether the problem exists or not, so I fleshed out the answer to include it, but also left the answer that addresses the problem shown by the data.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Even if the question says "less than -999", the code in the question says `> -999`. The complement of the `>` operator is not `<` but `<=`.

Comment: @Guffa ok but I used neither < or <= in my follow up, I used !=. So I'm struggling to understand the purpose of these comments. If you've proven that it works without change then vote to delete the question.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Read your answer. You are using "less than -999" as complement to "greater than -999".

Comment: @Guffa the part where i have quoted the OP? I'm using it to represent other valid values that are not -999.

Comment: @Guffa Either way, I'm happy with my interpretation of the question and the answer I've given.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Really? You are saying that "you are only checking where values are greater than -999" as if it was a problem because "the value dump you provided doesn't have any items that are less than -999". That's simply not true.

Comment: @Guffa I am highlighting the potential cause of the issue where items less than -999 were not being added to the list even though the statement from the OP on that issue is contradicted by the provided data set. This is all fairly obvious in my answer, but this is all against my interpretation of that quote.

Comment: @Guffa we have a misunderstanding going on here. I'm not saying its a problem because of the data, I'm saying the OP highlighted the problem in spite of the data. This is where I give up with the chat. I'm on my phone and this typing is getting annoying, and I still don't see the value in any of it.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Again, read your answer. You are saying that it's a problem to check for values greater than -999 because there are no values less than -999, but that is not true. There are values *equal to* -999. They are not *less than* -999 but they still are *not greater than* -999.

Comment: @Guffa I'm not saying it was a problem, I am interpreting the OPs statement that he once had the problem and that it was likely caused by the fact he was only checking for values greater than -999, therefore anything equal to or less would not make it into the collection. He then goes onto say that -999 was being used as a special value. I was just tackling what I thought he was getting at, I never said that checking for only -999 was a problem in its own right. So again this is a misunderstanding. It all stems off of how I have chosen to interpret the quoted statement...

Answer (score 6):

What you describe does not happen with the code that you have shown. It will add all values in the array from index 0 to index 49 that are greater than -999 to the list.

If the array is larger than 50 items, it won't use all items in the array. You should use the length of the array in the loop to get all items:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sarray.Length; i++)
```

(Even if you know that the array is always 50 items, it's a good idea to still use the `Length` property. That way the array will always use the entire array even if you change the length of the array in the future.)

#### Edit:

I tested your code with your data, and the list ends up with 40 items.

```
double[] sarray = {
  31411.0857, 31411.0902, 31411.0847, 31411.0858, 31411.0859, 31411.0479,
  31411.0649, 31411.0895, 31411.0944, 31411.0207, 31411.0683, 31411.0717,
  31411.075, 31411.0825, -999, -999, -999, -999, -999, -999, -999, -999,
  -999, -999, 31411.0156, 31411.0718, 31411.0719, 31411.0884, 31411.0885,
  31411.0936, 31411.0896, 31411.0897, 31411.0537, 31411.066, 31411.0661,
  31411.0556, 31411.0701, 31411.0731, 31411.0952, 31411.0716, 31411.0776,
  31411.0803, 31411.091, 31411.0911, 31411.0919, 31411.0919, 31411.0919,
  31411.0919, 31411.0919, 31411.0919
};

List<double> nums = new List<double>();
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  if (sarray[i] > -999) {
    nums.Add(sarray[i]);
  }
}

Console.WriteLine(nums.Count);
```

Output:

```
40
```

Comment: this is crazy! It works when I create the new code. but When I use the same things in my original code, it again gives me 27! I think there is  a bug! I am so sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
List<double> nums = new List<double>(sarray.Where(x => x > -999));
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this works, without having to iterate yourself:

```
List<double> nums = (from value in sarray 
                     where (value > -999) select value).ToList<double>();
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this _does_ iterate `sarray`, it just does it for you.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth You're right poor choice of words, obviously any solution will iterate `sarray`.